# how do I display list of URLS say maximum 50 per web page from MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I do have thousands of urls in my database. what I want to do is display all urls in multiple pages say number of URLS per page is 100 and alphabetically then when ever a user search for a URL info it should get updated on relevant page. for example if it is google.com then it should get updated on "G" page and no duplicate entry. how can I do this with PHP and MySQL??

Comment: are you talking about what the query should be? The LIMIT keyword in MySQL can be used to achieve exactly wat u want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fist of all alphabetically ordered list:

```
SELECT url_column_name 
FROM my_table 
ORDER BY url_column_name ASC
```

what you wanna do is a pagination you can read about pagination here: http://hype-free.blogspot.com/2008/10/efficient-sql-pagination-method.html

Answer (score 3):

You would need to combine a `WHERE` clause in your SQL with a `LIMIT 0,100` or something.

You can use the where clause to limit it by letter `WHERE name LIKE 'G%'` and you can use the limit clause to get the first 100 rows by doing `LIMIT 0,100`